# Filter child entities in querydsl query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to convert the c# linq query to java querydsl query.
But I'm struggling with it.
Here is the c# code:

```
var ssiDeclarationMasters = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.SsiDeclarationMasters
.Where(x => x.year == 2023)
.Select(x => new
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    IsConfirmed = x.IsConfirmed,
    SsiDeclarationPromotionLaws = x.SsiDeclarationPromotionLaws
    .Where(y => y.PromotionLawId == 5)
    .ToList()
})
.ToList();
```

Here is my java code to do that:

```
var c2 = queryFactory.selectFrom(ssiMaster)
            .rightJoin(ssiMaster.SsiDeclarationPromotionLaws, promotionLaw)
            .where(
                    ssiMaster.year.eq(2023),
                    promotionLaw.promotionLawId.eq(5)
            )
           .select(
                    ssiMaster.isConfirmed,
                    ssiMaster.name,
                    ssiMaster.SsiDeclarationPromotionLaws

                    );
```

This code doesnt filter ssiMaster.SsiDeclarationPromotionLaws table. It just gets all promotion results.
What am I missing?